# Looking for efficient Task Scheduler

Tags: php, sql, multithreading, queue, scheduled-tasks

I have several jobs that need to get completed X times and I have different workers with their own information.

In addition to that jobs have a date and I want to process a job Y times before it gets to the next job starting at the oldest job.

A worker shall only process a job one time.

Currently I'm using a mysql database to achive this along with php scripts as workers but there seems to be a bottleneck at about 50 jobs per second and I need to go faster so I have to look for alternatives.

My setup has the following tables:

```
jobs

job_id  | job_info  | last_processed    | times_executed    | to_be_done
1   | 949461321 | 05-04-2014 00:14:56   | 192               | 1000
2   | 356454214 | 05-04-2014 00:14:57   | 8                 | 200
3   | 321564642 | 05-04-2014 00:14:58   | 16                | 10000
4   | 546412131 | 05-04-2014 00:14:59   | 3                 | 50

workers 

worker_id   | specific_information  | status
1       | 4656439897543521456       | ok
2       | 6513165165465498498       | not_responsive
3       | 1046486479849870987       | not_responsive
4       | 6540498465494131131       | ok
5       | 6484654321654657498       | ok
```

Along with that I have the following setup (here in pseudo_code for simplicity):

```
$jobs_per_run = 10; // Process 10 jobs when the script runs
$workers_per_run = 5; // Process each job 5 times before it moves to the next job

FOR $i = 0; $i < $jobs_per_run; $i++ {
    SQL_QUERY "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE times_executed < to_be_done GROUP BY last_processed ASC"; // get least used job that needs processing
    FOR $j = 0; $j < $workers_per_run; $j++ {
        SQL_QUERY "SELECT * FROM workers WHERE status = 'ok' AND worker_id NOT IN($processed_workers)";
        IF job_was_executed_successfully {
            SQL_QUERY "UPDATE jobs SET times_executed = times_executed + 1, last_processed = NOW() WHERE job_id = $job_id";
        } else {
            SQL_QUERY "UPDATE workers SET status = 'not_responsive' WHERE worker_id = $worker_id"
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that explains what I need. I don't even know how this is actually called.

I've read about `queues`, `task schedulers` and `messaging systems` but the problem here is that I need to execute a job several times by different workers sorted by last_processed.

I think these constructs I've mentioned work like you throw some jobs in and they get executed one and another. With my setup I suppose I'd need to assign workers from the start and then for example put job 1 in 1000 times assigned to different workers.

There's a problem for me with that. Sometimes workers are not available all the time and If I enqueue worker 1 with job 2 now it would be useless if it got executed in a few minutes and worker 1 wouldn't be responsive at that time. That's why I assign a working worker to a job at execution time currently.

The `task scheduler` would need to be more managable than that, I'd need to be able to pause and resume single jobs and select them for workers based on different criteria that lies within their "table row".

I'd like to have 300+ workers active working on the queue system without problems. A worker executes a job within about 1 second so that would be 300+ jobs done per second.

Ideally I'd like to have a cloud setup like Amazon AWS where I have one instance to be the task scheduler and several other instances that perform the jobs.

What is the best possible setup to achive something like this? The mysql solution I have now seems most conveniant and fitting. Maybe there's a faster database for that job with similar features?

Answer (score 6):

Despite what our teachers told us, there *is* such a thing as a stupid question; this is the reason you didn't get a decent answer thus far.

Rather than ignoring that you asked the question, on this occasion, I'll take the time to explain why the question is stupid in the hope that future readers, as well as yourself, will benefit.

> I'd like to have 300+ workers active working on the queue system without problems

This shows a misunderstanding; it shows that you think your hardware is capable of executing 300 threads concurrently, **it is not**: I would wager *there won't be such hardware at our disposal in our lifetimes.*

[Multi-Threading in PHP with pthreads](https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782)

> There is a tendency to be wasteful; it’s a common misunderstanding to think that threading anything can make it faster, it cannot. More threads does not always equate to more throughput, in the same way as more water does not always equate to wetter.
>
> [image: more water !== wetter]
>
> Thinking outside the box is a prerequisite of a good multi-threaded programmer; common sense should dictate that more water does mean wetter, but if you consider the central point of the bottom of the bowl: Once it is wet, it does not matter how much water you place on top, it cannot get wetter ...
>
> Too much water, or threads, and you will drown.

You should read all of the quoted document, it should provide you a good understanding of what is possible, and how.

Comment: Hello Joe, thanks for your honest answer. I agree with you that multithreading doesn't always speed up things but in my case webrequests are involved which take around 1 second each where hardware does nothing. This one second is much of a slow down if I only run a single thread so I'm using multithreading to bridge that waiting time as good as as possible so the hardware uses its potential. My question wasn't about how to execute the workers but how to store and distribute my work so it maintains scalable. Mysql does a good job but it became a bottleneck and I was looking for alternatives.

Comment: Also, it _isn't_ mentioned that the workers have to be on _the same machine_. There might be 300 machines with 1 worker each. Sure multithreading won't help in this case either, but nowhere in the question multithreading comes up...

Comment: So it is, guess I misses that! Sorry if I came across a bit harsh.

Comment: (Warning, constructive criticism ahead!). I downvoted this - the 'stupid question' preface is, in my view, unnecessary. It is perhaps not quite the same as calling someone stupid, but it is I think quite close. In many cases this is counterproductive, as the good advice you have to offer is likely to be rejected out of hand - but Matthias has been very generous and thanked you for it anyway. I expect that would not be the usual experience for such a reply `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I have noticed about your queries is that you are selecting all records in your `FOR` loops.

Instead of GROUP by use ORDER BY, as I believe that is what you are trying to do and limit number of jobs in query itself:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs 
WHERE times_executed < to_be_done 
ORDER BY last_processed ASC LIMIT 10
```

As a job can only be done by a single worker you should consider using `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT * FROM workers 
WHERE status = 'ok' AND worker_id NOT IN($processed_workers) LIMIT 1
```

If you are planning to give same job to 5 available workers still limit your query:

```
SELECT * FROM workers 
WHERE status = 'ok' AND worker_id NOT IN($processed_workers) LIMIT 5
```

Now in PHP instead of `FOR`, use `WHILE` to lopp through jobs and workers recordsets.

Other thing that is interesting to find out is how long execution of each job takes. It looks like your solution is not asynchronous, so possibly jobs themselves create the bottleneck as opposed to queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Divide and Conquer](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Divide-and-Conquer) strategy explained by 0MQ might help you:

#### Terminology

First off, there are 2 meanings of the word "job" in your question:

1. There's the "job" which means the total amount of work that will eventually produce the final result. I'll keep calling that a *job*.
2. And there's 1 iteration of some process that needs to be run. So that's 1 single time a worker will do something. I'll call that a *task*.

So 1 *job* consists of X *tasks*.

#### The strategy

- Have a ventilator which will start a *job*. This means adding the initial *task* to a "command queue".
- Have an arbitrary number of workers that will do the actual work. A single worker will pull a single *task* from the "command queue", process it, and push the result to a "result queue".
- Have a sink that will collect the result from the "result queue". It can do 1 of 2 things:

  1. The *job* is not yet done (needs more iterations), so it will push a new *task* to the "command queue".
  2. The *job* is done, so it will store the final result somewhere.

For this to work the payload of a *task* needs to include the number of times a *job* needs to run and the number of times it has already run.

#### Different types of work

There are 2 approaches possible here:

1. Have multiple types of workers. You'll also need multiple "command queues", each type of worker needs to pull *tasks* from a queue dedicated to that type. The sink will also need to know (based on the payload of a *task*) to which "command queue" it needs to add a new *task*.
2. Have a single type of worker that knows how to do all the different tasks. Include the type of work that needs to be done in the payload of a *task*. This way the worker will know what to do.

Which of these approaches is more feasible depends on what the work actually is. So you'll have to choose yourself.

#### Advantages

The main advantages of this setup are:

- You can add as many workers as you like/need, which will run in parallel. You can even put them on different servers.
- You won't need a central data-store (like a SQL database) for running a complete *job*. You can still use the database as source to start a *job*, and/or to store the final result, but everything in between will be passed as payload.

#### Tools

You can choose any kind of message queue or task manager you like. You can find a nice list on [Queues.io](http://queues.io/).

I would advise you to also look at [React](http://reactphp.org/) (Event-driven, non-blocking I/O with PHP) which will help you with asynchronization.

Answer (score 0):

To get more throughput you have to use multi threading.

1. You can do it yourself by using [pthreads](https://www.php.net/pthreads).

**From PHP Site:** pthreads is an Object Orientated API that allows user-land multi-threading in PHP. It includes all the tools you need to create multi-threaded applications targeted at the Web or the Console. PHP applications can create, read, write, execute and synchronize with Threads, Workers and Threaded objects.

2. Use open source tools like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/). Its solving all of the your problem which you mentioned like *it will allow to create threads & leave them running, and reconnect it using other script to check jobs status.*

From **Gearman** Site:

Gearman provides a generic application framework to farm out work to other machines or processes that are better suited to do the work. **It allows you to do work in parallel, to load balance processing, and to call functions between languages.** It can be used in a variety of applications, from high-availability web sites to the transport of database replication events. In other words, it is the nervous system for how distributed processing communicates

Some Features as below:

1. Open Source
2. Multi-language
3. Fast
4. Embeddable
5. No single point of failure

Reference Link is as Below:

1. Rasmus' Blog: [Playing with Gearman](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/51-Playing-with-Gearman.html)
2. From PHP: [Gearman](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php)
3. [PHP multithreading (multitasking) on Windows](http://phplobby.com/php-multi-thread-on-windows-pthreads-configuration/) . I have not gone through this. Adding just for your reference here.

Answer (score 0):

To improve your performance, you can do 4 easy things:

- Use LIMIT in your queries to only fetch the needed number of rows
- Only call the query once fetching multiple rows, then looping through the results
- Don't use grouping in your queries (These are not cases for grouping, just user ORDER BY)
- Check your table indexes (benchmark this to verify improvement): jobs needs an index on last_processed, workers an index on status

$jobs_per_run = 10; // Process 10 jobs when the script runs
$workers_per_run = 5; // Process each job 5 times before it moves to the next job

```
SQL_QUERY "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE times_executed < to_be_done ORDER BY last_processed ASC LIMIT $jobs_per_run";
while (FETCH ROW) {
    SQL_QUERY "SELECT * FROM workers WHERE status = 'ok' LIMIT $workers_per_run";
    WHILE (FETCH ROW) {
        IF job_was_executed_successfully {
            SQL_QUERY "UPDATE jobs SET times_executed = times_executed + 1, last_processed = NOW() WHERE job_id = $job_id";
        } else {
            SQL_QUERY "UPDATE workers SET status = 'not_responsive' WHERE worker_id = $worker_id"
        }
    }
}
```

There might be some difference in scheduling if you have less jobs than $jobs_per_run or if the number of available workers falls below $workers_per_run. In these cases, there will be less processing per run, but the run will also be over much faster.
In any case every run will now do up to 11 SELECTS instead of 50 like before.

If you always have many workers, you can even fetch a list of up to 50 workers at the beginning of the run and fetch them progressiveli in the inner loop. This would reduce the number of SELECTS to 2 per run.